# Hide button based on value of custom attribute in select option when chnaged

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown selector, and a button I need to hide or show depending on the value of a custom attribute in the select options.

HTML

```
<div id="container-3">
<div id="inside-container">
<select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="1kg" selected="selected" stock-status="true" class="attached enabled">1kg &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- $75.90 &nbsp;- (In Stock)</option>
  <option value="2kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">2kg - $119.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
  <option value="3kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">3kg - $174.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
  <option value="5kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">5kg - $262.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
  <option value="10kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">10kg - $482.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
  <option value="20kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">20kg - $823.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery I came up with, but isn’t working:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#pa_size').change(function(){
    if($("#pa_size").find("option:selected").attr('stock-status') == "false") {
      $("#container-3 .single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
    } else {
      $("#container-3 .single_add_to_cart_button").show();
    }
  });
}); 

/* 
I also tried using the following if statement:
  if($('#pa_size option:selected').attr("stock-status") == "false") {
*/
```

I set up a jfiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/inspirednz/q09t8k2d/).

1. My first question, is how do I make this jQuery work, and have I gone about it a suitable way (aside from whatever the error is)?

I have another related question ...

2. What’s the best way to also run this before there’s been any user interaction? Such as, the page has loaded, and there’s a default value selected in the dropdown. I’d like the same test to run against it, so that if the `stock-status` is already `false` then the button will hide.

Comment: Check the 2 first div's of your code. That is the problem.

The `“` will make your html look like `<div id="“container-3”">`

Comment: Ok. Although I only added those divs as an after-thought, whilst setting up the question here. So my jQuery was failing before I tried testing for a div, etc.

Comment: If i change the `“` then your code works just fine

Comment: Yeah ... me too. I’ve since discovered jFiddle somehow dropped my JS framework selection. So it was no longer using `jQuery 3.31` which I set at the start. Glad to know my code actually works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in the comment, the reason why your code is not working is:

The `“` will make your html look like `<div id="“container-3”">`

The selector here `$("#container-3 .single_add_to_cart_button")` will return no elements because `#container-3` does not exist. In your case the id of the element looks like `“container-3”`

Also if you want to make sure the button is hidden/shown depending on the default value then you can add `.trigger("change")`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pa_size').change(function() {
    if ($("#pa_size").find("option:selected").attr('stock-status') == "false") {
      $("#container-3 .single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
    } else {
      $("#container-3 .single_add_to_cart_button").show();
    }
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-3">
  <div id="inside-container">
    <select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
      <option value="1kg" stock-status="true" class="attached enabled">1kg &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- $75.90 &nbsp;- (In Stock)</option>
      <option value="2kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">2kg - $119.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="3kg" selected="selected" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">3kg - $174.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="5kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">5kg - $262.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="10kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">10kg - $482.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
      <option value="20kg" stock-status="false" class="attached enabled">20kg - $823.90 &nbsp;- (No Stock)</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’ve now figured out that my jquery wasn’t working because for some reason jFiddle dropped the fact I’d selected `Javascript + jQuery 3.31` as the framework! However, it’s good to know the `.trigger(“change”)` code.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your code and fiddle.
Your code is working as expected in fiddle and I don't see any bug.

Q1. How to run jQuery code?

Ans. => I can see you have not added jQuery CDN using Script tag to run jQuery code.
You must have to add below script tag in your HTML page to run jQuery.

jQuery CDN link -> `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Q2. What’s the best way to also run this before there’s been any user interaction?

Ans => Below is the example of setting default option to select tag onLoad.

`$('#pa_size').val("3kg");`

find fiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/7410quvf/3/

And to access access values of custom attributes of selected option below line can be useful.

`$("#pa_size").find("option:selected").attr('stock-status')`

find fiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/m29d8aby/1/

Hope this would clear you about your questions.

Comment: Thank you. See my comment above, re the fact it wasn't running because a setting got dropped in jFiddle. Regarding running jQuery, thanks for that tip. The code is on a Wordpress site, so jQuery library is already loaded by default. Regarding detecting stock status before user interaction: the site will select first option by default, so what I need is to determine its `stock-status` value to either hide or show the button on page load.